# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-manifest

How to Fix This issue, before the project worked well,  now I open it, I'm getting this issue
[image]

[image]

Comment: "before the project worked well"... but "before" what? :) did you change something in the meantime?

Comment: no, I did not change anything in the project, 
other some projects also not working ,

I updated Android Studio,
and also tried in old version Android studio , still same error